# Core Data Automatic Update Inquery

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I have a question concerning Core Data and how, if at all, Entities get updated automatically.

Basically, let's say I fetch some data X. X has an inverse to-many relationship with Y. Then a method get's called to update an attribute in X. Does one have to fetch the data again? or will X automatically get the updated data?

If this is not possible, that's fine. I was just curious as I saw a post a few days ago. I don't remember the details, but I think it spoke about how to have the NSManagedObjects automatically update/refresh their data and was curious if this is something true, or a setting you must set, or just not possible.

I'm actually in the process of refetching the data to update the table. This is fine with me, but again, I am just curious if what I read is true or if I misunderstood the post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data model state changes, an update needs to take place somewhere, in order for changes to be reflected in the UI. If you use `NSFetchedResultsController`, updates to the UI can be managed more easily. [Here is some documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFetchedResultsController)

Comment: So if I do not use NSFetchResultsController, which I don't, would I have to make my own methods to **refresh** the data? (That's what I'm doing now)